# Android HTTPClient "No Peer Certificate" over HTTP

Tags: android, http

I'm building an Android app that accesses an openshift URL over HTTP. And I keep getting an error "No peer certificate".

When I run... openssl s_client -connect mySubDomain.rhcloud.com:80 -showcerts

I get... CONNECTED(00000003) 11940:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_cl nt.c:567:

Which is odd. I don't know too much about this stuff, but why is there a certificate over HTTP?

I've tried a lot of the things other people have mentioned on here and nothing seems to work.  Most of the questions here are also for HTTPS too.

John

Comment: Is it possible that there's a redirect going on from http to https?

Comment: I don't think so, because when I goto the URL with my browser, it stays on HTTP.

Comment: What's the actual URL (mySubDomain) that you're going to?  When I go to www.rhcloud.com it redirects to https:..openshift.com

Comment: Here's the actual URL: http://faraim-mfc.rhcloud.com/data/manifest.xml

Comment: That's the URL you're trying to access over HTTP?  I don't see why that doesn't work either.  It didn't do any redirection or urlrewrite. Sorry, can't help.